# US citizen nonresident income tax

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, netherlands

I'm a United States citizen and I have an opportunity to work abroad. I was told by a friend that up to $103K of income earned abroad is not taxed by the IRS.  First of all, is this true?  Also, will I have to pay taxes in the country I'm going to but which I'm not a citizen of?  I want to know specifically for the Netherlands and Kuwait.

Comment: The latter question depends on the country, so you should probably be specific rather than general; we have tax treaties with some countries, not with others.

Comment: I see, I did mention Netherlands or Kuwait as examples

Comment: What kind of work will you be doing? There are certain exceptions to federal tax withholding for US citizens abroad.

Comment: @MichaelC. I will be doing computer programming.

Comment: @Exocomp And how long will you be there for?

Comment: @MichaelC. I'll be there for 5 years.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your first question, your friend is correct, except for the amount -
 it's $101,300 not $103,000. This is due to the [Foreign earned income exclusion](https://turbotax.intuit.com/tax-tools/tax-tips/General-Tax-Tips/Filing-Taxes-While-Overseas/INF19130.html)

> One tax break for expatriates is the Foreign Earned Income Exclusion.
>   If an American moves abroad, he or she can exclude foreign-earned
>   income up to $101,300 as of 2016 from U.S. taxation. To qualify, that
>   person must have lived outside the United States for 330 days in 12
>   consecutive months, said Wilson, a partner in the Denver law firm of
>   Holland & Hart.
>
> That means an expatriate making $75,000 overseas would pay no taxes,
>   although he or she still must file IRS Form 1040 and claim the
>   exclusion. If the expatriate makes $105,000, tax must be paid on the
>   difference between his or her salary and $101,300, or $3,700. But if
>   the expatriate visits the United States for more than 35 days in that
>   period, the benefit is lost.
>
> If there’s no government where the expatriate is living, the exclusion
>   can’t be claimed. Wilson recalled a case in which Americans tried
>   without success to claim the exclusion because they were living in
>   Antarctica. The exclusion also can’t be claimed on the high seas, he
>   said.

As for your second question, there is [no personal income tax in Kuwait](https://www.taxesforexpats.com/kuwait/us-tax-preparation-in-kuwait.html). For the Netherlands, you will [typically have to file and pay taxes](http://www.expatica.com/nl/finance/Understanding-the-Dutch-income-tax-system_103981.html).